# FlipView Datatemplate fails to bind on custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

## TL;DR

Using MahApps' `FlipView` with a custom `DataTemplate`, binding fails to update when using a custom UserControl.

## Issue

Trying to use MahApps's FlipView to host a custom UserControl for each view. For testing purposes, my UserControl looks like this (testing this on [MetroDemo sample project](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/develop/src/MahApps.Metro.Samples/MahApps.Metro.Demo))

**XAML**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MetroDemo.ExampleViews.CustomImageControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MetroDemo.ExampleViews"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid x:Name="ControlContainer">
        <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Code Behind**

```cs
namespace MetroDemo.ExampleViews
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CustomImageControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CustomImageControl : UserControl
    {
        public ImageSource SourceImage
        {
            get => (ImageSource)this.GetValue(SourceImageProperty);
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(SourceImageProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          nameof(SourceImage),
          typeof(ImageSource),
          typeof(CustomImageControl),
          new PropertyMetadata(OnSourceImageChanged));

        private static void OnSourceImageChanged(DependencyObject data, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var control = (CustomImageControl)data;
            if (control is null || !(args.NewValue is ImageSource image))
                return;

            control.SourceImage = image;
        }

        public CustomImageControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ControlContainer.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I'm using this custom user control within a `DataTemplate` that FlipView uses, replacing [this bit here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro.Samples/MahApps.Metro.Demo/ExampleViews/OtherExamples.xaml#L27-L29) for:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageDataTemplate" x:Shared="False">
    <local:CustomImageControl SourceImage="{Binding Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue={x:Static DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}, Converter={mah:NullToUnsetValueConverter}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

When flipping to the next view, it animates but for some reason it keeps the same first bound image.
It seems that the binding is failing somewhere but I can't see where. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I comment out the following it works like expected:

```cs
        private static void OnSourceImageChanged(DependencyObject data, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            //var control = (CustomImageControl)data;
            //if (control is null || !(args.NewValue is ImageSource image))
            //    return;

            //control.SourceImage = image;
        }
```

it basically gets a new value and sets it as a new `ImageSource` which will call the `OnSourceImageChanged`. In this void it sets a new `ImageSource` which will call this `OnSourceImageChanged` again.

Comment: This was it! Had that code from a while and didn't even considered it could be wrong. WPF kills me sometimes.